# My website doesnt load the correct css parameters

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a MOOC application using Django for the back-end and simple html for the front-end.

I gave one updated on 'styles.css' to make the face of the site a little friendlier but he simply refuses to use the colors I've decreed.

[Here](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc) u can find my full app.

An example, in the [/core/templates/base.html](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc/blob/master/core/templates/base.html) file I created a div called footer:

```
...
<div class="footer">
        Tâmer MOOC - Uma simples plataforma de ensino a distância
</div>
...
```

So, I setup some configs in the [/core/static/css/styles.css](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc/tree/master/core/static/css) file, here is the footer stuff (Im really newbie in css so, maybe the error is obvious):

```
.footer {
    background: #2d3e50;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

But when I run the server and go to the site, i see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjVxl.jpg)
Basically, the bg color was meant to be `#2d3e50` and actually is `#111` and the font color was meant to be `#fff` and actually is `#666`. And this is for all configs ive done, he refuses do reload the configs. The css settings being displayed are the old ones.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Open css url, press CTRL+Shift+R. If does not help - run `collectstatic` again. If does not help show settings.py part for static files.

Comment: My question is: why my application does not follow the settings that are in my css file and how to solve this.
Ivan u can find the settings.py file on my github, the link to this is in the post above.

Comment: So, collectstatic doesnt work (Ive tested but I have just 1 static folder for all apps so...) and I really dont understand what u mean saying "press CTRL+SHIFT+R opening css url" sorry.

Comment: Show your template source (which is supposed to load css file) and settings for static files (like STATIC_ROOT and so on).

Comment: All tamplates have the same problem, U can find some of them [here](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc/tree/master/core/templates). In the [settings.py](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc/blob/master/tamermooc/settings.py) ive this: `STATIC_URL = '/static/' ` and   MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tamermooc', 'media') and MEDIA_URL = '/media/ '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CTRL+SHIFT+R thing solve my problem, thank u so much Ivan!

I do not know how to manipulate html/css files very well but by pressing "CTRL + SHIFT + I" on the home page and then pressing "CTRL + SHIFT + R" the file 'styles.css' has been loaded completely. Again, thank you Ivan!